# Postgres index the big table for hashing

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using postgres to run this simple query on Data base of tpc-ds 1TB:

```
select cp_start_date_sk, ws_sold_date_sk
from catalog_page, web_sales
where ws_sold_date_sk = cp_start_date_sk;
```

the query plan is:

```
                                     QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Hash Join  (cost=34981958.72..381924075.14 rows=24611155542 width=8)
    Hash Cond: (catalog_page.cp_start_date_sk = web_sales.ws_sold_date_sk)
    ->  Seq Scan on catalog_page  (cost=0.00..1836.00 rows=60000 width=4)
     ->  Hash  (cost=25981508.32..25981508.32 rows=720036032 width=4)
         ->  Seq Scan on web_sales  (cost=0.00..25981508.32 rows=720036032 width=4)
```

as it can be seem the big table is inserted into hash. Allegedly this is not optimal because the hash will be bigger and the time to run it will be slower than build the hash from the small table. Can anyone explain that?

update: the schema:
[image]

[image]

update2:
psql version:
psql (PostgreSQL) 14beta1

config definitions:

```
max_worker_processes = 1

max_parallel_workers = 1

max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 1

shared_buffers = 125GB

effective_cache_size = 250GB

work_mem = 125GB
```

Comment: can you add the create table + create index statements? The indexes aren't being used at all ...

Comment: Nothing is "inserted into" - the hashtable to do the join is build up in memory. If there isn't enough memory to do that, Postgres will switch to a different join strategy.

Comment: Totally unrelated, but: you might want to start using the "modern" explicit JOIN operator that was introduced in SQL nearly 30 years ago, rather than the implicit and fragile join conditions in the WHERE claause

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com.

Comment: I created the table with "tpcds.sql" file and the relation with "tpcds_ri.sql" file that given with tpc-ds query here https://github.com/gregrahn/tpcds-kit/tree/master/tools.
the schema of the tables is in updated quation

Comment: What is your question, why it uses the join order it does, or how to index this?  Those are entirely different questions.

Comment: My quation is why postgres not inserts the small table into hash. that is the efficient way to do the join (with or without using index)

Comment: What is your version of PostgreSQL?

Comment: And what is your setting of work_mem?

Comment: version: psql (PostgreSQL) 14beta1
config definitions:
max_worker_processes = 1

    max_parallel_workers = 1
 
   max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 1
 
   shared_buffers = 125GB

    effective_cache_size = 250GB

    work_mem = 125GB

Answer (score 1):

There are no indexes in the columns used in your query. Add the following indexes and the query time should be improved (check the query plan again):

```
CREATE INDEX idx_cat ON catalog_page (cp_start_date_sk);
CREATE INDEX idx_ws ON web_sales (ws_sold_date_sk);
```

Also, try to use proper `JOIN`s instead of using multiple tables in the `WHERE` clause - the latter might give you a huge headache if you accidentally cross join multiple large tables.

```
SELECT cp_start_date_sk, ws_sold_date_sk
FROM catalog_page c 
JOIN web_sales w ON w.ws_sold_date_sk = c.cp_start_date_sk;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=722f1b46b9421c776101e5f8ebae9ec0)

Comment: Actually I checked the explicit join, even replaced between the tables and always got the same plan. I didn't try to use indexes because I don't try to fix the problem, but to realize why postgres does such inefficient plan

Comment: In fact, a supporting index is needed for **all** FK fields. (otherwise, updates or deletes in the referred table would be very costly) Plus: do an ANALYZE on the table after creating the index.